# how to use landscape right only in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode9

I don't want my app to change the orientation to landscape on the left side but just keep it in the right if the user changes the orientation of the screen. How do I do it ?

Comment: Apple specifically states that you should avoid this. If you support landscape, you are supposed to support both landscape orientations. So make sure you have a really good reason for this (and hope they agree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **General**  settings of your app, go to deployment info , uncheck landscape left

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more specific control over screen orientations, just override `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` of your controller(s):

Objective-C

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Swift

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
}
```